# React devtools "highlight updates" in V4

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

Did they remove the ability to highlight updates in **[React Dev Tools V4](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/15/new-react-devtools.html)**? I can't seem to find it anywhere. I do miss it so.

You know, this thing? [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Highlight updates has been released in React Dev Tools V4

https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/16989

Answer (score 3):

> The honest answer is we didn't quite have the time to implement it, and didn't consider it important enough to block all the other features from releasing.

You can read more about *if* they're going to implement it again here:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16437

Comment: Thanks for the link~ I wasn't the only one missing that feature 