# How do you highlight updates in React Dev Tools V4?

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

## EDIT: duplicate of [React devtools "highlight updates" missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57563530/react-devtools-highlight-updates-missing)

How do you enable 'highlight updates' in React Devtools **V4**?

This feature in **V3** was pretty nice. Is it even still possible in V4?

---

V4 was released [Aug 15, 2019](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/15/new-react-devtools.html)

Comment: In v4 React Menu in Dev tools is split into two different parts, Components and Profiler. But, flashing has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @skyboyer, yea it is a dupe. :( Should I delete this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## EDIT: "highlight updates" has been released for V4

https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/16989

---

## At the time of this answer,

"highlight updates" is not yet ready for React Devtools **V4**, [according to the react team](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16437#issuecomment-522244087).

### See this github issue:

[Devtools V4: Where is Highlight Updates? #16437](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16437)

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking about **Chrome dev tools Paint Flashing**?

Add Rendering panel along side Elements, console, Network, Performance, etc.. via

**Options > More Tools > Rendering** and select **Paint Flashing** from given options.

Comment: Hey, thats really cool! So you have my upvote :D, but I'm not referring to Chrome dev tools Paint Flashing. It was specific to react dev tools